# UI Test Tool like Snoop/Silverlight Spy for Android

Tags: android

I want to see visual tree like Snoop(WPF), Silverlight Spy(WindowsPhone, Silverlight app)? Is there any tool available for Android application?

Comment: Today there is one, definitive answer to this question, and that's Android Studio Layout Inspector https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/layout-inspector.html . When this question was asked AS didn't even exist yet, but still this question should be re-opened now that there is a real answer, since this page is still the nr 1 Google hit for a number of variations on what the OP was asking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure how close they are to what Snoop and SIlverlight spy do as I have not worked with them but here goes.

[UI/Application Exerciser Monkey](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/monkey.html)

> The Monkey is a program that runs on your emulator or device and generates pseudo-random streams of user events such as clicks, touches, or gestures, as well as a number of system-level events. You can use the Monkey to stress-test applications that you are developing, in a random yet repeatable manner (From Android Developer docs).

[scirocco](http://code.google.com/p/scirocco/)

> Scirocco is a UI test automation tool for Android. It’s able to perform test on several devices and making test reports with screenshots in succession. (from scirocco docs).

[Robotium](http://code.google.com/p/robotium/)

> Robotium is a test framework created to make it easy to write powerful and robust automatic black-box test cases for Android applications. With the support of Robotium, test case developers can write function, system and acceptance test scenarios, spanning multiple Android activities. 
>   Robotium has full support for Activities, Dialogs, Toasts, Menus and Context Menus (from robotium docs).

Comment: Note that as of March 2013 scirocco latest version 2.0 (released Jul 2011) is built on top of Robotium version 2.3, however scirocco does not currently appear to be nearly as active as Robotium (latest release version 4.0, Feb 2013).  For this reason I would avoid scirocco.